# Print largest number out of given digits - Java

Tags: java, android, numbers

First I would apologize if my question seems not clear.

I want output to be the largest possible number from user input. Example:

```
input: x = 0; y = 9; z = 5;
output: 950
```

I tried something like the below code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    class LargestOfThreeNumbers{
       public static void main(String args[]){
          int x, y, z;
          System.out.println("Enter three integers ");
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

          x = in.nextInt();
          y = in.nextInt();
          z = in.nextInt();

          if ( x > y && x > z )
             System.out.println("First number is largest.");
          else if ( y > x && y > z )
             System.out.println("Second number is largest.");
          else if ( z > x && z > y )
             System.out.println("Third number is largest.");
       }
    }
```

The code above will print something like: `The seconde number is largest`. That is correct the way I define the conditional statements. But how do I get `950` as final result? I know some logic is required here but my brain doesn't seem to produce it.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using  java 8 [IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html):

```
    int x = 0, y = 9, z = 5;
    IntStream.of(x,y,z).boxed().sorted( (i1,i2) -> Integer.compare(i2, i1)).forEach( i -> System.out.print(i));
```

Comment: It's a pleasure to see you again. This solution seems simplier

Comment: If one can use streams

Comment: I'm actually trying to port the path finding algo you wrote on android but I'm hardly stuck. Could yoou please have a look?

Comment: Sure. Post it and leave a comment

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this to print the numbers in order:

```
// make an array of type integer
int[] arrayOfInt = new int[]{x,y,z};
// use the default sort to sort the array
Arrays.sort(arrayOfInt);
// loop backwards since it sorts in ascending order
for (int i = 2; i > -1; i--) {
    System.out.print(arrayOfInt[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What should I import to resolve the type of ``Array`` ? ``java.lang.sql`` or ``java.lang.reflect`` ? None of the above seems resolve ``sort``. I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: import java.util.Arrays; for the Arrays.sort()

Comment: Weird. Was not listed among the quick fixes. Thank you

Comment: Yeah man no problem, if you think this answer is correct do you mind checking the green check mark as the answer to this question? Have a good one!

Comment: Sure I will, but seems not to resolve Array... Is Eclipse broken or something?

Comment: try Arrays with an 's'

Comment: Yeah, works with an s! I can definitely say my brain is tired as I didn't even notice this!

Comment: BUT: With your solution, the result is different. I tried with x = 5, y=3 and z=6. I got 210 instead of 653. The solution of @Elliot Frisch works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can find the maximum with successive calls to `Math.max(int, int)` and the minimum with calls to `Math.min(int, int)`. The first number is the `max`. The last is `min`. And the remaining term can be determined with addition of the three terms and then subtraction of the min and max (x + y + z - max - min). Like,

```
int max = Math.max(Math.max(x, y), z), min = Math.min(Math.min(x, y), z);
System.out.printf("%d%d%d%n", max, x + y + z - max - min, min);
```

Comment: Thanks; I was thinking of a cascading if stattements or a list the iterating over the elements. This solution seem to be the best. Let's me test I'll come back to you

Comment: By the way: What %d is used for? I guess it should be an escape or something?

Comment: @esQmo_ `%d%d%d` specifies a format of three decimal integer values, and `%n` is a newline. See also [`Formatter` JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: Oh, thak you alot.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work

```
    ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner val = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter a value");
        x = val.nextInt();
        myList.add(x);
    }
    myList.sort(null);
    String answer = "";
    for (int i = myList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        answer += myList.get(i).toString();
    }
    System.out.println(answer);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But like the other solutions, only for digits (0 - 9). The behavir is different with numbers. (exemple 10, 100, 100 will output 100010010 which is correct, but I would like to be able to output 111000000, I don't even know if it makes sense though lol).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, it works with numbers 0 to any 10 digit number

Comment: Oh, just take the input and then throw it into a sort algorithm like quicksort

Comment: My main need is to make largest numbers from digits, so if I have 1000, 100 and 10, should be 11100000 as it is greater than 100010010 (I think ?). Anyway your solution works great. Wish I could accept them all

Comment: oh, Quicksort... never heard of.. Will make a search and find out what it is

Comment: Oh, BTW, how do I make the console restart when the result is found instead of running the program again?

Comment: You can put all of the code in a while loop, and while true it just keeps running. You would just need to have a condition to cause a break, or make a boolean variable and have it change to false at some point. Or you could just quit the program.