# Print largest number out of given digits

Tags: java, android, sorting

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052073/print-largest-number-out-of-given-digits-java), but in android. i'm trying to get input from an EditText the display the final result into a TextView on button click.

I'm having trouble trying to adapt the three answer, which OP says are all working.

How can I get the value from the TextView then display the result in the TextView?

The below approach seems to work but the output is 000, I guess because I nothing is stored in the arrayList

```
input = (Edittext)findViewById(R.id.et_input);
output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_output);
    ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Scanner val = new Scanner(System.in); //can't figure out how to get user input from editText
            int x = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                x = val.nextInt();
                myList.add(x);
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                myList.sort(null);
            }

            for (int i = myList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                answer += myList.get(i).toString();
            }


            send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    output.setText(answer);
                }
            });
```

Comment: How far have you got? Do you have the number and just need to display it in a TextView now?

Comment: I need to get from user input. I just edited my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print largest number out of given digits - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052073/print-largest-number-out-of-given-digits-java)

Comment: @aquaballin It's already mentioned in the question

Comment: ah yes input seems to be the issue now

Comment: @aquabalin, it's not really a diplicate as I linked that question. The case seems a bit different from a noob like me

Comment: ditch the scanner, we don't use that class in android. Use `input.getText().toString()` to get the input

Comment: Okay, but how do I deal with : ``x = val.nextInt();`` ? I tried that approach already

Comment: forget that part, it belongs to the scanner. Use android methods. Get the input from the edittext and loop over the characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick

Add your numbers in the EditText seperate each digit by **" "(space)**

```
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String[] digits = input.getText().toString().split(" ");
            ArrayList<Integer> digitArray = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String digit : digits) {
                if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(digit))
                    digitArray.add(Integer.parseInt(digit));
            }
            Collections.sort(digitArray);
            StringBuilder largestPossibleNumber = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = digitArray.size(); i > 0; i--) {
                largestPossibleNumber.append(digitArray.get(i - 1));
            }
            output.setText(largestPossibleNumber.toString());
        }
    });
```

no need of the

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner val = new Scanner(System.in); //can't figure out how to get user input from editText
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            x = val.nextInt();
            myList.add(x);
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            myList.sort(null);
        }

        for (int i = myList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            answer += myList.get(i).toString();
        }
```

---

**UPDATE**
If you don't want to use any separator than use following code

```
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String enteredText = input.getText().toString();
            ArrayList<Integer> digitArray = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0 ; i< enteredText.length(); i++) {
                if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(String.valueOf(enteredText.charAt(i))))
                    digitArray.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(enteredText.charAt(i))));
            }
            Collections.sort(digitArray);
            StringBuilder largestPossibleNumber = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = digitArray.size(); i > 0; i--) {
                largestPossibleNumber.append(digitArray.get(i - 1));
            }
            output.setText(largestPossibleNumber.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work but input == output. I get the same result that was entered in input

Comment: input == output. What do you mean by that?

input is your EditText and output is your TextView

Comment: I mean, I get the same input as result. ex: 233 = 233. Should output 332

Comment: Ooh Let me check

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check that. and if that meets your goal than accept this answer

Comment: No, doesn't work. The imput si the same as output, but seems to work when there is a zero in the input but the zeroes are ditched. exemple: 025 = 52, 536 = 536

Comment: You need give input as 0 2 5 than it will gv you output as 520 like that you need to separate each digit by space while giving input

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi *you need to separate each digit by space while giving input* - or you could fix your code so that is not needed

Comment: @TimCastelijns The input given is needed to be seperated somehow so i have used space to seperate it. So each and every digit need to be seperated by the space. If you want to pass integers **(10,25,12)** than you must enter in the editText as **10 25 12**

Comment: a requirement like that should be included in the question

Comment: @Krul I have updated my answer and have given you another solution in which you can simply add input as 052 and it will give you output as 520 similarly 050 = 500

Comment: Thanks alot, this solution worked.I didn't understand what you meant by ``Add your numbers in the EditText seperate each digit by " "(space)`` I was thinking the space would be added automatically

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // use textview to display the result
    output = (TextView)findViewByIf(R.id.textview1);
    // use a button to activate sorting once you have the edittexts filled
    sortNumbersButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    // use EditText(s) to get values from user
    input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
    // set a listener for a button so that we can activate sorting
    sortNumbersButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                // use a string array to store string values from input
                string[] strings = input.getText().toString().split(" ");
                // use the editText getText() method to pull values from UI
                int[] intArray = new int[] {Integer.parseInt(strings[0]),
                    Integer.parseInt(strings[1]),
                    Integer.parseInt(strings[2])};
                // sort the values in the array in ascending order
                Arrays.sort(intArray);
                // use stringbuilder to append string values for output
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                // loop backwards since it sorts in ascending order
                for (int i = 2; i > -1; i--) {
                    sb.append(intArray[i]);
                }
                // set the textview value of the sorted integers! and done
                output.setText(sb.toString());
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: This get input from three textViews? So is it not possible to get from one textView then?

Comment: oh no you can certainly use one EditText, just split the string's spaces using split(" ");

Comment: hey I edited the answer to be closer to what you may need

Comment: Thanks for answering but doesn't work. I'm getting some errors. ``int[] intArray = new int[3] {Integer.parseInt(strings[0]),
                    Integer.parseInt(strings[1]),
                    Integer.parseInt(strings[2])};`` This line throws an error: missing ``;``

Comment: Crashes the app on button click throwing ``java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:`` on  ``Integer.parseInt(strings[0]),``